# Python Set Comprehension Nested in Dict Comprehension

Tags: python, nested, dictionary-comprehension, set-comprehension

I have a list of tuples, where each `tuple` contains a `string` and a number in the form of:

```
[(string_1, num_a), (string_2, num_b), ...]
```

The strings are nonunique, and so are the numbers, e.g. `(string_1 , num_m)` or `(string_9 , num_b)` are likely to exist in the list.

I'm attempting to create a dictionary with the string as the key and a set of all numbers occurring with that string as the value:

```
dict = {string_1: {num_a, num_m}, string_2: {num_b}, ...}
```

I've done this somewhat successfully with the following dictionary comprehension with nested set comprehension:

```
#st_id_list = [(string_1, num_a), ...]
#st_dict = {string_1: {num_a, num_m}, ...} 
st_dict = {
    st[0]: set(
        st_[1]
        for st_ in st_id_list
        if st_[0] == st[0]
    )
    for st in st_id_list
}
```

There's only one issue: `st_id_list` is 18,000 items long. This snippet of code takes less than ten seconds to run for a list of 500 tuples, but over twelve minutes to run for the full 18,000 tuples. I have to think this is because I've nested a set comprehension inside a dict comprehension.

Is there a way to avoid this, or a smarter way to it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a double loop, so you take O(N**2) time to produce your dictionary. For 500 items, 250.000 steps are taken, and for your 18k items, 324 *million* steps need to be done.

Here is a O(N) loop instead, so 500 steps for your smaller dataset, 18.000 steps for the larger dataset:

```
st_dict = {}
for st, id in st_id_list:
    st_dict.setdefault(st, set()).add(id)
```

This uses the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to ensure that for a given key (your string values), there is at least an empty set available if the key is missing, then adds the current `id` value to that set.

You can do the same with a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

st_dict = defaultdict(set)
for st, id in st_id_list:
    st_dict[st].add(id)
```

The `defaultdict()` uses the factory passed in to set a default value for missing keys.

The disadvantage of the `defaultdict` approach is that the object *continues* to produce default values for missing keys after your loop, which can hide application bugs. Use `st_dict.default_factory = None` to disable the factory explicitly to prevent that.

Comment: Wow, hugely helpful, thank you! Added bonus: I was not aware of dict.setdefault() and have been emulating that functionality with if statements elsewhere! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two loops when you could do in one loop like this:

```
list_1=[('string_1', 'num_a'), ('string_2', 'num_b'),('string_1' , 'num_m'),('string_9' , 'num_b')]

string_num={}
for i in list_1:
    if i[0] not in string_num:
        string_num[i[0]]={i[1]}
    else:
        string_num[i[0]].add(i[1])

print(string_num)
```

output:

```
{'string_9': {'num_b'}, 'string_1': {'num_a', 'num_m'}, 'string_2': {'num_b'}}
```